# Unable to use string as class atribute (see the Update 4)

Tags: c++, string, class, segmentation-fault, class-members

Take this class as example:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class One {
private:
  string * text;
public:
  One();
  ~One();

  void setText(string value);

  string uppercase();
  string lowercase();
  string inverted();
};
```

its implementation:

```
#include "libone.h"

One::One() {
  text = new string();
}

One::~One() {
  delete text;
}

void One::setText(string value) {
  //
}

string One::uppercase() {
  string result(*this->text);

  for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {
    char c = result[i];
    c = toupper(c);
    result[i] = c;
  }

  return result;
}

string One::lowercase() {
  string result(*this->text);

  for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {
    char c = result[i];
    c = tolower(c);
    result[i] = c;
  }

  return result;
}

string One::inverted() {
  string result;

  string temp(*this->text);
  for(int i=temp.size(); i>0; i--) {
    result = result + temp.at(i);
  }

  return result;
}
```

used here:

```
#include <libone.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  One one;
  one.setText("Kleber Mota de Oliveira");
  cout << "text:" << one.uppercase() << endl;
  cout << "text:" << one.lowercase() << endl;
  return 1;
}
```

programa compile without errors or warnings, but when I try to run the executable, I got an segmentation fault.

I tried use `string text` as atribute too, but the same problem happens.

Something similar is happening with another project mine. Anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong here?

**Makefile for libone.cpp**

```
all: libone

libone: ${obj_dir}/libone.o
    g++ -shared -o ${release_dir}/libone.so ${obj_dir}/libone.o -Wl,--out-implib,${release_dir}/libone.a

${obj_dir}/libone.o: src/libone.cpp
    g++ -fPIC -c src/libone.cpp -o ${obj_dir}/libone.o
```

**Makefile for Main.cpp**

```
all: main

main: ${obj_dir}/Main.o
    g++ -L ${release_dir} -o ${release_dir}/project -Wl,-rpath='./' ${obj_dir}/Main.o -lone -ltwo

${obj_dir}/Main.o: Main.cpp
    g++ -I ${lib_one_header} -I ${lib_two_header} -c Main.cpp -o ${obj_dir}/Main.o
```

**Makefile**

```
export base_dir := ${CURDIR}
export obj_dir := ${base_dir}/build
export release_dir := ${base_dir}/release

export main_src := ${base_dir}/src
export lib_one_header := ${base_dir}/src/libone/include
export lib_one_src := ${base_dir}/src/libone
export lib_two_header := ${base_dir}/src/libtwo/include
export lib_two_src := ${base_dir}/src/libtwo

lib_one := ${lib_one_src}
lib_two := ${lib_two_src}
libraries := $(lib_one) $(lib_two)
player    := ${main_src}

.PHONY: all $(player) $(libraries)
all: $(player)

$(player) $(libraries): | ${obj_dir} ${release_dir}
    $(MAKE) --directory=$@

$(player): $(libraries)
```

**UPDATE 1**

If I try build `libone.cpp` and `Main.cpp` together with:

```
g++ libone.cpp Main.cpp -o main
```

generating only one executable, everything works fine. But if I build with the Makefiles, to get separate library and executable, then I got this Segmentation fault error.

**UPDATE 2**

result of the backtrace command in gdb shell (using `string text` as atribute:

```
#0  0x00007ffff7bd84ec in __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7ea6296 in std::char_traits<char>::copy (__n=23, __s2=<optimized out>, __s1=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/char_traits.h:409
#2  std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_S_copy (__n=23, __s=<optimized out>, __d=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:359
#3  std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_S_copy (__n=23, __s=<optimized out>, __d=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:354
#4  std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign (this=this@entry=0x7fffffffd9ce, __str="Kleber Mota de Oliveira")
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:272
#5  0x00007ffff7ea662f in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::assign (__str=..., this=0x7fffffffd9ce)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:1355
#6  std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator= (this=0x7fffffffd9ce, __str=...)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:680
#7  0x00007ffff7fba255 in One::setText(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) () from ./libone.so
#8  0x000055555555637d in main ()
```

(using `string * text` as atribute):

```
#0  std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign (this=this@entry=0x55555556bee0beb0, __str="Kleber Mota de Oliveira")
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:260
#1  0x00007ffff7ea662f in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::assign (__str=..., this=0x55555556bee0beb0)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:1355
#2  std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator= (this=0x55555556bee0beb0, __str=...)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:680
#3  0x00007ffff7fba2a6 in One::setText(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) () from ./libone.so
#4  0x000055555555637d in main ()
```

**UPDATE 3**

With this update, only the first method in `Main.cpp` is executed. In the second I got a Segmentation fault error:

```
class One {
private:
  char * text;
public:
  One();
  ~One();

  void setText(char* value);

  string uppercase();
  string lowercase();
  string inverted();
};
```

implementation:

```
void One::setText(char* value) {
  text = value;
}

string One::uppercase() {
  string result = text;

  for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {
    char c = result[i];
    c = toupper(c);
    result[i] = c;
  }

  return result;
}

string One::lowercase() {
  string result(text);

  for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {
    char c = result[i];
    c = tolower(c);
    result[i] = c;
  }

  return result;
}

string One::inverted() {
  string result;

  string temp(text);
  for(int i=temp.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
    result = result + temp[i];
  }

  return result;
}
```

**UPDATE 4**

with the code below, all methods called in `Main.cpp` are executed, but display a bunch of rubish in the screen. An example:

```
text:�Q���
text:�Q���
text:���t
```

class declaration:

```
class One {
private:
  char * text;
public:
  One();
  ~One();

  void setText(char* value);

  const char * uppercase();
  const char * lowercase();
  const char * inverted();
};
```

implementation:

```
const char * One::uppercase() {
  string result = text;

  for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {
    char c = result[i];
    c = toupper(c);
    result[i] = c;
  }

  return result.c_str();
}

const char * One::lowercase() {
  string result(text);

  for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {
    char c = result[i];
    c = tolower(c);
    result[i] = c;
  }

  return result.c_str();
}

const char * One::inverted() {
  string result;

  string temp(text);
  for(int i=temp.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
    result = result + temp[i];
  }

  return result.c_str();
}
```

**UPDATE 5**

class declaration:

```
class One {
private:
  char * text;
public:
  One();
  ~One();

  void setText(const char * value);

  const char * uppercase();
  const char * lowercase();
  const char * inverted();
};
```

implementation:

```
#include "libone.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

One::One() {
  text = new char[1];
  text[0] = '\0';
}

One::~One() {
  delete [] text;
}

void One::setText(const char * value) {
  delete [] text;

  int size = 0;
  for(; value[size] != '\0'; size++);

  text = new char[size];
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    text[i] = value[i];
}

const char * One::uppercase() {
  char * result;

  int size = 0;
  for(; text[size] != '\0'; size++);

  result = new char[size];
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    if (text[i] >= 65 && text[i] <= 90)
      result[i] = text[i] - 32;
    else
      result[i] = text[i];
  }

  return result;
}

const char * One::lowercase() {
  char * result;

  int size = 0;
  for(; text[size] != '\0'; size++);

  result = new char[size];
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    if (text[i] >= 33 && text[i] <= 58)
      result[i] = text[i] + 32;
    else
      result[i] = text[i];
  }

  return result;
}

const char * One::inverted() {
  char * result;

  int size = 0;
  for(; text[size] != '\0'; size++)

  result = new char[size];
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    result[i] = text[size-(i+1)];
  }
  result[size] = '\0';

  return result;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "libone.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  One one;
  one.setText(argv[1]);

  cout << one.uppercase() << endl;
  cout << one.lowercase() << endl;
  cout << one.inverted() << endl;

  return 1;
}
```

output:

```
+leber -ota de /liveira
Kleber Mota de Oliveira
arievilO ed atoM rebelK
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
zsh: IOT instruction (core dumped)
```

Comment: Allocating `std::string` directly on heap is like eating soup with two spoons: it may work, but it isn't a good or practical idea.

Comment: What is better in cases like this? Use `char*`, even with c++?

Comment: @KleberMota No, simpy use `std::string` without `new`'ing it

Comment: Just to be clear, `std::string` keeps long strings on heap. There is Small String Optimization (SSO) which tries prevent use of heap to speed up code. So when you do `std::string` on heap you are discarding effort made to speed up strings (SSO) and add extra obsolete indirection. You should just use `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good reason to make the `text` member be a `string*` pointer (especially since you are not following the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) to manage the pointer properly, but we can ignore that for this exercise since you are not making any copies of the `one` object).

But, let's just say, for the sake of argument, that you need a pointer, for whatever reason.  The only mistakes your code is making are:

- in `setText()`, you are not assigning `value` to `text`, eg:

```
void One::setText(string value) {
  *this->text = value;
}
```

- in `inverse()`, you are accessing the `temp` string out of bounds, it should be like this instead:

```
string One::inverted() {
  string result;

  string temp(*this->text);
  for(int i=temp.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
    result = result + temp[i];
  }

  return result;
}
```

The rest of the code you have shown works fine:

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/4HJ0z9)

**UPDATE**:

The problem with your code is that you are implementing `One` in a dynamic library. As such, you can't pass non-POD types, like `std::string`, across the library boundary.  So, try something more like this instead:

```
class One {
private:
  char * text;
public:
  One();
  ~One();

  void setText(const char *value);

  char* uppercase();
  char* lowercase();
  char* inverted();
};

void freeString(char *str);
```

```
#include "libone.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

One::One() {
  text = new char[1];
  *text = '\0';
}

One::~One() {
  delete[] text;
}

void One::setText(const char *value) {
  delete[] text;
  text = new char[strlen(value)+1];
  strcpy(text, value);
}

char* One::uppercase() {
  int len = strlen(text);

  char* result = new char[len+1];
  strcpy(result, text);

  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    unsigned char c = result[i];
    c = toupper(c);
    result[i] = c;
  }

  return result;
}

char* One::lowercase() {
  int len = strlen(text);

  char *result = new char[len+1];
  strcpy(result, text);

  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    unsigned char c = result[i];
    c = tolower(c);
    result[i] = c;
  }

  return result;
}

char* One::inverted() {
  int len = strlen(text);

  char *result = new char[len+1];

  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    result[i] = text[len-1-i];
  }

  return result;
}

void freeString(char *str) {
    delete[] str;
}
```

```
#include <libone.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  One one;
  one.setText("Kleber Mota de Oliveira");

  char *str = one.uppercase();
  cout << "text:" << str << endl;
  freeString(str);

  str = one.lowercase();
  cout << "text:" << str << endl;
  freeString(str);

  str = one.inverted();
  cout << "text:" << str << endl;
  freeString(str);

  return 1;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
class One {
private:
  void * text;
public:
  One();
  ~One();

  void setText(const char *value);

  char* uppercase();
  char* lowercase();
  char* inverted();
};

void freeString(char *str);
```

```
#include "libone.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

One::One() {
  text = new std::string;
}

One::~One() {
  delete static_cast<std::string*>(text);
}

void One::setText(const char *value) {
  *static_cast<std::string*>(text) = value;
}

char* One::uppercase() {
  std::string temp = *static_cast<std::string*>(text);

  for(size_t i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
    unsigned char c = temp[i];
    c = toupper(c);
    temp[i] = c;
  }

  char* result = new char[temp.size()+1];
  strcpy(result, temp.c_str());
  return result;
}

char* One::lowercase() {
  std::string temp = *static_cast<std::string*>(text);

  for(size_t i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
    unsigned char c = temp[i];
    c = tolower(c);
    temp[i] = c;
  }

  char *result = new char[temp.size()+1];
  strcpy(result, temp.c_str());
  return result;
}

char* One::inverted() {
  std::string &str = *static_cast<std::string*>(text);

  std::string temp;
  temp.reserve(str.size());

  for(size_t i = str.size(); i > 0; i--) {
    temp += str[i-1];
  }

  char *result = new char[temp.size()+1];
  strcpy(result, temp.c_str());
  return result;
}

void freeString(char *str) {
    delete[] str;
}
```

```
#include <libone.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  One one;
  one.setText("Kleber Mota de Oliveira");

  char *str = one.uppercase();
  cout << "text:" << str << endl;
  freeString(str);

  str = one.lowercase();
  cout << "text:" << str << endl;
  freeString(str);

  str = one.inverted();
  cout << "text:" << str << endl;
  freeString(str);

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: I did all the changes you suggested, but still got the same Segmentation fault error. If I compile all source code together (`g++ libone.cpp Main.cpp -o main`), everything works fine. Instead, if I build `libone` as a separate library (as I intend to do, since after this works I will expand this to use this concep in other projects) and link to the binary generated from `Main.cpp`, only in this case I got the error.

Comment: @KleberMota that would have been useful info to have up front. In that case, what kind of library are you building? Static? Dynamic? In the latter case, you can't use non-POD types like `std::string` across library boundaries.

Comment: it's a dynamic library (`libone.so`). sorry for do not clarify this (i thought posting the Makefile were enough). What type I should use in this case?

Comment: @KleberMota You will have to use a `char[]`/`char*` string instead. Otherwise, you will have to type-erase the `std::string` so the main app can't see it, but the library can still use it internally

Comment: Ok, I just tried that. Right now, the first method called in the `Main.cpp` is executed with no problems, but in the second I get the segmentation fault (the debugger indicates this happens when the code tries get the size of the string). I am doing the type-erase you suggested: inside each method, I copy the content of the `char * text` atribute to a localvariable `string result(text)` (or at least I am intending to copy the content. What's better: `string result(text)` or `string result = text`?)

Comment: @KleberMota you are going to have to update your question to show what you actually tried. By type-erasing, I was referring to declaring `text` as a `void*` and then casting it to `std::string*` when needed. Or even hiding the entire `One` object itself behind a `void*` pointer and wrapper functions.

Comment: I just add an update #3 with the new source code.

Comment: @KleberMota Update 3 is still using `std::string` over the library boundary. You were on the right track using `char*` pointers for everything in Update 4. The reason it returns garbage is you are returning a `char*` to the data of a local `std::string` that gets destroyed on `return`, thus you are returning a dangling pointer to invalid memory. You would have to use `new[]` or `strdup()` to extend the lifetime of the `char[]` data, and then the caller would have to `delete[]`/`free()` that memory when done using it. Same thing with the `SetText()` method to copy the caller's input data.

Comment: @KleberMota I updated my answer with some examples.

Comment: Ok, then I still got segmentation fault errors in my machine with the code from your answer. I try make my own based on the observations you told me, and got the code I just added in the update #5. No segmentation fault, but strange characters appearing in the output for the `uppercase` method, and both `uppercase` and `lowercase` methods are not doing what they are expected to do. And this weird message after the output.

Comment: @KleberMota you are not null-terminating your strings. You need to add 1 to the size when allocating the `char[]` so you have room to include a `'\0'` char at the end. Also, your `main()` is leaking the returned strings. My examples I gave you take care of both issues.